# Got two times reputation for editing question/Suggested Edits

Tags: discussion, support, edits, suggested-edits, reputation

I've edited [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29862303/i-dont-know-why-a-modal-window-does-not-display) two times. Both the time edit got approved. So I've got +4 reputation for edits. However It's not deliberate act to get reputation though. It was my bad. So question, User's have chance to get multiple times  reputation for trivial edits or normal edits.

[Here's the revision history for the same](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/29862303/revisions)

Comment: Trivial Edit's would be rejected, so if your edit was accepted, it means it's worth keeping, then you deserve the rep. And also, the edit you made is useful as it removed unnecessary formalities

Answer (score 3):

Edits are supposed to fix everything wrong in the post. Each time you fail to do that you run the risk that your edit will be rejected.

It's certainly possible, however for the original poster to add aditional details after you've edited a question so the availability of additional points mainly covers that possibility.